# BigQuery delete duplicate records using CTE & Nested records

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, duplicates

Requirements :

- Table `analytics.SANDBOX.bookings` has a nested record transaction (which in turn have column transationId)
- I like to delete all but one duplicate records from this table where date, uniqueId, hashedEmail are identical for records where first 8 character of nested column transactionId is same as that of value in the date column. Also want to delete only 'Web' records, typeGroup='New'

My solution

- CTE gives me all but one  duplicate records
- Outer select gives me a date, uniqueId, hashedEmail & transactionId of records that need to be deleted (please note that in this case I am selecting transactionId which will help me to identify records to be deleted)
- I make a STRUCT that identifies rows to be deleted

Problem - Column transactionId which identifies what to delete is sitting in the nested column & delete DML does not like a nested column. Please note if I remove transactionId from STRUCT then I am deleting all duplicate records but I want to keep one intact.

Syntax error: Expected end of input but got ","

```
delete from  analytics.SANDBOX.bookings p, UNNEST(transaction) AS q
WHERE STRUCT(date,uniqueId, hashedEmail,transactionId) IN (
--This select statement will pick transactionId for all but one duplicate records which I would like to delete
Select STRUCT(date,uniqueId, hashedEmail,transactionId) from (
WITH cte as (
    --find out all the records which are duplicates
    SELECT  row_number () over(partition by date,uniqueId, hashedEmail order by uniqueId) as rn, *
    FROM analytics.SANDBOX.bookings o
    ,UNNEST(transaction) AS t
    --select only those rows where first 8 chacters of nested column transaction.transactionId matches with date
    WHERE substring(transactionId,1,8) = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',date)
    AND visit.device.platform='Web'
    AND t.typeGroup = 'New'
    ) 
Select * from cte where rn > 1
))
```

Here is sample data
[image: Here is sample data]

Comment: Pls try to provide table data/schema as a file and not image for easy reproduction.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the schema of the table where the "transactionId" is nested?